# Ionic Home Page Blank

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app I'm serving locally. I get a response from the server and the HTML elements are also filled, however there's nothing showing on the Home screen.[image: Response + generated HTML ionic tags]

Comment: In case the image doesn't show I uploaded it on https://www.datafilehost.com/d/a53c2467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit.. this **cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport** and ***cdVirtualFor** were somehow not functioning. I ended up replacing the **cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport** with **ion-card** and then the ***cdkVirtualFor** with ***ngFor**

```
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport cdkDropList itemSize="20" class="example-viewport" 
     (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

    <ion-item *cdkVirtualFor="let t of tickets" class="example-item" 
      href="/tabs/(details:{{t.qn_uid}})" cdkDrag>

    </ion-item>

 </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable extensions from [chrome://extensions/](http://chrome://extensions/) and check whether this problem appears or not.

Comment: I just did that. Nothing changes

Comment: Disable all extensions and check, please.

Comment: This issue is for any of  your installed chrome extensions. First disable all extensions and try to enable one by one to find the extension for which this issue has appeared.